# Simple: creating tables in database

Tags: php, mysql, database, create-table

Really simple question. I forgot how to deal with this specific script. With a PHP file I create tables in mysql database. I have `$query` variable with the following commands:

```
$query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table1` (
              `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
                      `status` int(11) NOT NULL
              )ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

              CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table2` (
              `something` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
              `whatever` text NOT NULL
              )ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
         ";
```

It works only if I exec one single command. When I run multiple CREATE / INSERT / DROP ... commands it doesn't work. For sure there's a mistake with the syntax maybe **;** and **,**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mysql_query()` doesn't support multiple statements in the same call.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

> mysql_query() sends a unique query (multiple queries are not supported) to the currently active database on the server that's associated with the specified link_identifier.

Answer (score 1):

You're problem doesn't comes from the SQL (well, I didn't checked it properly to be honest), but from mysql_query (assuming you're using it) : it does't allow multiple request.
http://php.net/manual/fr/function.mysql-query.php

Answer (score 1):

As others have stated, the mysql_query() function doesn't support multiple queries in a single call.

On a somewhat related note, if you are able you should look into using mysql_i or PDO in place of the old mysql_*() functions, which are inferior for too many reasons to list here.

[http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php%5d)

[http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php%5d)